# Grep: command for getting a key value from another command

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am creating a kafka instance creation script and I want to gather the bootstrap server from a describe command.

The command to gather the kafka instance details is.

```
rhoas kafka describe
```

the output looks something like this

```
"admin_api_server_url": "server-address",
  "billing_model": "standard",
  "bootstrap_server_host": "foobar",
  "browser_url": "browser-url",
  "cloud_provider": "aws",
```

What I am looking for is a grep command that will return just `foobar` from `"bootstrap_server_host"`

I have tried
`rhoas kafka describe | grep bootstrap_server_host` which returns the whole line.

```
"bootstrap_server_host": "foobar",
```

I just want `foobar` by itself.
Thanks

Comment: Is it json? Then you should use something like jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
rhoas kafka describe | grep bootstrap_server_host | cut -d \" -f 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use gnu-grep with `-P` for perl-compatible regular expressions

```
rhoas kafka describe | grep -oP 'bootstrap_server_host":\s*"\K[^"]+'
```